# Keyboard scrolls the screen in unexpected way

Tags: flutter, dart

I built a simple application. I have a `TextField` within a panel sheet. This is how it looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNdcm.png)

Now, when I tap the `TextField`, to open the keyboard,
this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKwS3.png)

As you can see, the panel goes up. I don't want it. I want the panel to get the scroll attribute. So if content within the panel sheet overflows, the panel would have scroll. So basically, the panel sheet should look static. it should not pushed up by the keyboard.

To achieve it I used the `SingleChildScrollView` Widget to make the panel scrollable.
But yet, it didn't help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ));
  runApp(_MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.rubikTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
          defaultPanelState: PanelState.OPEN,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          minHeight: 0,
          maxHeight: 650,
          backdropEnabled: true,
          body: Text("BLA"),
          panel: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(157, 157, 157, 1),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(157, 157, 157, 1),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  maxLines: 15,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean don't scroll the screen when your keyboard is open correct?

Comment: In your Scaffold you can set this property to false like resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false

Comment: @Abhijith then, the keyboard would overlap the `TextField` and I don't want it

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I want the panel sheet to be scrolled. not the whole screen.

Comment: try to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` inside your **Scaffold()** Widget